# If $\widetilde{L} =$ splitting field of all irreducible polynomials over $L$ of prime-power degree, is $\widetilde{\Bbb{Q}} = \overline{\Bbb{Q}}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

For a field $L$, let $\widetilde L$ be the splitting field of all irreducible polynomials over $L$ having **prime-power degree**.

> **Question**: Do we have $\widetilde{\mathbf Q}=\overline{\mathbf Q}$?

My money is on "no", because I see no obvious reason why it should be true. If the answer is indeed negative, can one say what degree occurs as the smallest degree of an $f\in \mathbf Q[X]$ which does *not* split in $M$?

In any case, it seems quite difficult.

*A variation*:  We have a chain $$L \subset \widetilde L \subset \widetilde {\widetilde L} \subset \dots$$
Let $\widehat L$ be the limit of this chain. Is it even true that $\widehat{\mathbf Q}=\overline{\mathbf Q}$? Does the chain stabilize? The field $\widehat{\mathbf Q}$ has the strange property of having no finite extensions of prime-power degree. Correspondingly, the Galois group $\text{Gal }(\overline{\mathbf Q}/\widehat{\mathbf Q})$ has the strange property of having no open subgroups of prime-power index...

For $L$ a finite field, it is easy to see that $\widetilde{L}=\overline{L}$. We obviously have $\widetilde{\mathbf R}=\overline{\mathbf R}$. I do not know if $\widetilde{\mathbf Q_p}=\overline{\mathbf Q_p}$, or if $\widehat{\mathbf Q_p}=\overline{\mathbf Q_p}$. (*Edit*: Every finite Galois extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ is solvable, and I believe it follows from this that $\widehat{\mathbf Q_p}=\overline{\mathbf Q_p}$.)

**Addendum**: The question [has been answered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168952/is-my-field-algebraically-closed) (positively) by David Speyer at MO. (David: if would like to copy & paste your answer here as well, I will gladly accept it!)

Comment: Hmm, is there any particular reason you're using "prime-power" instead of just "prime"?

Comment: @Nishant Not really! Both are interesting questions. Which one is easier to answer will ultimately depend on what the answer to either is.

Comment: One potential proof idea converted into a group theory problem: are all finite groups $G$ images of groups that have all possible subgroups of maximal prime power index?

Comment: @seaturtles: Are you assuming the inverse Galois problem there?

Comment: Here is an idea, which I am not sure will work (or maybe it is just rephrasing the question). If I take an irreducible poly $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of composite degree, say $degf=pm$ for $p$ prime. Is $f\in M_p[x]$ reducible? (Here $M_p$ is splitting field of all irreducible degree $p$ polynomials). Eg take $x^6-2$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but is equal to $(x^3-\sqrt{2})(x^3+\sqrt{2})$ in $M_2[x]$. Then keep reducing $f$ to get it with coefficients in $M$ and a product of linears.

Comment: @zcn - Not exactly; overreaching by proving something for all finite groups does not mean we are assuming the inverse Galois problem. (If the answer to my group theory problem is "yes" then Bruno's question is answered, regardless of the status of the IGP. By the way, my idea is essentially taking compositums of fixed fields of maximal prime-power index subgroups of Galois groups of arbitrary number fields.) However it is optimistic, in the sense that theoretically the approach I gave could fail in full generality yet a tightened version of it would work while IGP has a negative answer.

Comment: @seaturtles: That's exactly what I was referring to - I only see your reformulation as equivalent, in the presence of IGP. I agree that it may be stronger than necessary though

Comment: You want to read Joseph Shipman's recent article on this in Math. Intelligencer, **29 (4)**, (2007), 9-14: (Improving the fundamental theorem of algebra*. Shipman addressed precisely this family of questions. For instance: If $K$ is a field such that every polynomial in $K[x]$ of prime degree has a root in $K$, then $K$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: @Andres: I thought so too, but in fact the result is less relevant than it seems. Shipman does not assume that the polynomials are irreducible.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, yes. I figured the actual question had negative answer (and now I see you showed precisely that), but still had some hope that Shipman's arguments could tell us something. These arguments are quite soft, the main tool being some combinatorics dating back to work of John Conway in the 70s. This is perhaps a drawback of the argument, but it indicates that there is still room for improvement there.

Comment: The answer I gave below fails at the very first step (I incorrectly translated the question into a question about extensions). I'll need to keep thinking. Thanks to @sea turtles for pointing out my blunder.

Comment: Here's a possible suggestion for a proof: show that the real closure of $\Bbb Q$ is a subfield of $M$ (i.e. every polynomial of an odd degree in $M[x]$ has a root there); then show that $-1$ is the sum of squares in $M$, and conclude that $M$ must be $\overline{\Bbb Q}$.

Comment: @Asaf: I don't see how you can get the first step off the ground (and the first step is all you need since clearly $M$ contains $i$). The crucial point is that the polynomials of odd degree you're talking about don't need to be irreducible, and in fact their irreducible factors can all have non-prime-power degree, e.g. some polynomials of degree $21$ are a product of irreducible polynomials of degrees $6$ and $15$. This is the same as the problem you run into when you try to use Joe Shipman's version of the fundamental theorem, which is stronger than what you're using.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Yeah, I wasn't sure that it's gonna work. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal : I am probably very naive here, but to answer the first question, is it possible to compute the absolute Galois group of $\widetilde{\mathbb Q}$ over $\mathbb Q$ and try to conclude something from there?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Compute in what sense though? For instance, what does it mean to compute the absolute Galois group of $\mathbf Q$?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal : I don't know, in the same way that the absolute Galois group is some inverse limit of I don't know what because I don't understand infinite algebraic extensions very well, I thought that the absolute Galois group of your thing would also be some kind of inverse limit

Comment: @Patrick All infinite Galois groups are uncountable. This already ruins all hope for a useful group presentation in the usual sense (say in finitely many generators and relations). The best hope is to give a useful presentation in the category of profinite groups.

Answer (score 10):

This is not a solution.

Here is what I hope is a correct restatement of the problem. Let me introduce the following conditions on an algebraic extension $L$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ which I don't have any imaginative names for:

> **P1:** $L$ is the compositum of extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ of prime power degree.
>
> **P2:** $L$ fits into a tower of P1 extensions. Equivalently, $L$ is the compositum of towers of extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ of prime power degree.

When a P1 (resp. P2) extension is Galois, its Galois group satisfies the following corresponding conditions:

> **P1:** $G$ has subgroups $H_1, ..., H_n$ of prime power index with trivial intersection.
>
> **P2:** $G$ has subgroups $H_1, ..., H_n$ with trivial intersection each of which fits into a tower $H_k \subseteq H_{k, 1} \subseteq H_{k, 2} \subseteq ... \subseteq H_{k, m} \subseteq G$ of subgroups each of which is of prime power index in the next.

The first question is equivalent to the question of whether every finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ occurs as a subextension of a P1 extension. The second question is equivalent to the question of whether every finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ occurs as a subextension of a P2 extension. These translate (imperfectly) into the following group-theoretic questions via the Galois correspondence:

> **Question:** Is every finite group a quotient of a finite P1 (resp. P2) group?

(I say imperfectly because we also need both groups to occur compatibly as the Galois groups of a pair of finite Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. If the answer to the above question is "yes," we don't necessarily know that the answer to the original question is "yes," but if the answer to the above question is "no," we may be able to construct a counterexample to the original question conditional on solving a special case of the inverse Galois problem.)

Instead of solving the problem let me explain my mistake. I thought that "subextension of a P1 extension" was equivalent to "a P1 extension," but the obvious argument fails: if $L \subseteq \bigcup_i K_i$ (where by $\bigcup$ I mean compositum in a fixed Galois extension containing $L$ and the $K_i$) it does not follow that $L \subseteq \bigcup_i (L \cap K_i)$; an explicit counterexample is that

$$\mathbb{Q}(i) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \cup \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$$

but the corresponding compositum of intersections is just $\mathbb{Q}$.

The corresponding mistake on the finite group side is perhaps even more insidious: it is to incorrectly assume that every quotient of a P1 group is P1. One reason this is an attractive assumption is that every nilpotent group is P1 (since a finite nilpotent group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups), and nilpotent is a property that passes to quotients!

Nevertheless the obvious argument fails: if $G \to G/N$ is a quotient map and $H_i$ are subgroups of $G$ of prime power index with trivial intersection, it's still true that their images $H_i N / N$ have prime power index in $G/N$ (this corresponds to taking the intersections $L \cap K_i$ in the above argument) but false that their intersection is necessarily trivial (this corresponds to the compositum failing to contain $L$ in the above argument) because $N$ can introduce additional relations. The example Galois corresponding to the above example is to take

$$G = C_2 \times C_2, H_1 = (0, 1), H_2 = (1, 0), N = (1, 1).$$

However, for all I know it might still be true that every quotient of a P1 (resp. P2) group is P1 (resp. P2). If someone has a proof of that it would imply that my original counterexample (the group [$G = A_6$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group%3aA6) is neither P1 nor P2 and occurs as the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial of degree $6$) still works. So:

> **Auxiliary question:** Is every quotient of a finite P1 (resp. P2) group P1 (resp. P2)?

Note that a counterexample to the auxiliary question for P1 is necessarily not nilpotent. It's also the case that every solvable group is P2 and that this is also a property that passes to quotients, so a counterexample to the auxiliary question for P2 is necessarily not solvable.

Comment: [This is also not a solution](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b9/MagrittePipe.jpg). :-)

Comment: Someone should prove that $A_6$ isn't a quotient of a finite P2 group. I played around with this for awhile and you get some strange-looking conditions but I couldn't find a contradiction from them.

Comment: The answer for P1 is clearly yes, and you can even prescribe the prime $p$: every finite group $G$ is quotient of the wreath product $C_p\wr G$ ($C_p$ is cyclic of order $p$), which admits $G$ as subgroup of index $p^{|G|}$, and having trivial intersection of conjugates (because $G$ acts faithfully on $C_p^G$). Of course this answers negatively the expectation that P1 be stable by quotients.

Comment: Moreover since P1 implies P2, this answers positively your question for P2 as well, and since $Alt(6)$ fails P2, this answers negatively the auxiliary question for P2.

Comment: @YCor: very nice! I have to admit I am surprised. But to turn this into an answer to the original question one now has to solve a somewhat harder version of the inverse Galois problem for these groups...

Comment: Well I'm not sure it's harder, since given a finite extension $\mathbf{Q}\subset L'$, one has to construct an abelian extension $L'\subset L''$ with some prescribed properties.

Comment: ... which was eventually done by David Speyer in the MathOverflow version: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168952/is-my-field-algebraically-closed#comment427889_168952